# django-cms not prompted for super user account when syncdb

Tags: admin, django-cms

When I am trying to configure django-cms, when ran syncdb it is not prompted for super user account, how I can login as admin now?

I am following this tutorial

http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably had an error during syncdb. Run:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```